Accessing a child's property via reflection
I have these two classes as a test, one inherited by the other. The real code that the test is based on is a DLL so I don't want to expose every property to the users of the DLL. I would like to be able to access the child's properties from the parent via reflection.
Public Module App
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim child As New ChildClass()
    child.Run()
  End Sub
End Module

Public MustInherit Class ParentClass
  Public Sub Run()
    [GetType].GetProperty("ProtectedProperty").GetValue(Me).ToString() 'Error
    [GetType].GetProperty("ProtectedFriendProperty").GetValue(Me).ToString() 'Error
    [GetType].GetProperty("FriendProperty").GetValue(Me).ToString() 'Error
    [GetType].GetProperty("PublicProperty").GetValue(Me).ToString() 'Success
    End
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class ChildClass
  Inherits ParentClass
  Protected Property ProtectedProperty As String = "Protected"
  Protected Friend Property ProtectedFriendProperty As String = "ProtectedFriend"
  Friend Property FriendProperty As String = "Friend"
  Public Property PublicProperty As String = "Public"
End Class

I would have expected any of the Friend properties to be accessible from the parent, but only the Public property doesn't throw an error. Is there something I'm missing?

It's a little weird for the base class to be trying to muck around in the derived class members.  Perhaps this is signaling that one or more of these properties should be Protected MustOverride?

In your code, the issue is because the default behavior of GetProperty only considers public properties.
To access non-public properties such as Protected, Protected Friend, or Friend, you need to specify appropriate BindingFlags.
Like this:
Public MustInherit Class ParentClass
    Public Sub Run()
        Dim bindingFlags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Public

        Dim protectedProp = Me.GetType().GetProperty("ProtectedProperty", bindingFlags)
        If protectedProp IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine(protectedProp.GetValue(Me).ToString())
        End If

        Dim protectedFriendProp = Me.GetType().GetProperty("ProtectedFriendProperty", bindingFlags)
        If protectedFriendProp IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine(protectedFriendProp.GetValue(Me).ToString())
        End If

        Dim friendProp = Me.GetType().GetProperty("FriendProperty", bindingFlags)
        If friendProp IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine(friendProp.GetValue(Me).ToString())
        End If

        Dim publicProp = Me.GetType().GetProperty("PublicProperty", bindingFlags)
        If publicProp IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine(publicProp.GetValue(Me).ToString())
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Adding the correct binding flags should take care of it.
Note that the Protected property is accessible because it is inherited by the parent class, and BindingFlags.NonPublic includes protected members in the search.
The Friend and Protected Friend properties are accessible because BindingFlags.NonPublic allows access to them as long as they are within the same assembly.
This way should enable your ParentClass to access all the properties of the ChildClass using reflection, regardless of their access levels.

That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I had assumed that Protected would work too but got thrown off when Friend didn't work. I didn't realize that GetProperty was the culprit since it only looks at Public.
